# How can i set display flex in my react slider?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-slick

This is my slider

```
<Slider {...settings}>
  <div style={{ 'display': 'flex !important' }}>
    <ArrowsToolComponent key={name} color={color} />
    <ZoomTool key={name} color={color} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <GridToolComponent key={name} color={color} />
    <CropToolComponent disabled={disabled} key={name} color={color} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <FlipTool disabled={disabled} key={name} color={color} />
    <PriorityToolComponent disabled={disabled} key={name} color={color} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <CopyFileToolComponent disabled={false} key={name} color={color} />
    <CancelFileToolComponent disabled={disabled} key={name} color={color} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <InsertTextBox key={name} color={color} />
    <InsertImageBox key={name} color={color} />
  </div>
</Slider>
```

How can i set display: flex to the div in my slider? There is no info in react-slick docs about it. It`s always inline-block by default.

Answer (score 0):

When writing components using React, we can accept different props *other than the required ones*, and deconstruct them in our component. It seems that  from this library does support passing `style` [props](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/src/slider.js#L205).

If there is no default props, you would be able to use the React `style` property, e.g:

```
<Slider {...settings} style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
   { /* rest of the code */}
</Slider>
```

If the component has `defaultProps`, React renders the component using them,  **unless the parent overrides it**. So you can also create a Parent `<div>` with your required styles, which could be:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
 <Slider {...settings}>
   { /* rest of the code */}
 </Slider>
</div>
```

- React.js Docs about [Rendering elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element).

Comment: slider disappears if I use style in wrap div.. I can change anything what I want if I use special css class for my div(background, color, etc). But not the display(even with !improtant)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Slider {...settings} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
```